# Reordering Cell Array by Array of Indices

Tags: matlab, cell-array, matrix-indexing

Suppose I have a cell array `x` and an integer array `y`:

```
x = {'apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear'};
y = [2 4 3 1];
```

In fact, `y` represents indices of `x`. I want to now create a cell array `z` with the elements of `x` reordered as specified by the order of these indices. This would give me:

```
z = {'orange', 'pear', 'banana', 'apple'};
```

Can I do this in one line without having to loop through each element and place it in `z` in turn?

Comment: I've only tried a very exhaustive approach where I do the reordering myself in a loop, i.e. for each index in the new `z`, find the corresponding element in `x` by using the respective index from `y`, and inserting that into `z`. But I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in Matlab in just one line?

Comment: Sorry, downvoting. This is too basic Matlab (as is evident from [CST-link's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24435337/2586922)).

Comment: I disagree, upvoting because I think this is useful: the indexing of cell arrays is a bit tricky for newcomers (i.e. when to use `{ind}` vs `(ind)`). Yes the docs (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html) quickly elucidate why it makes sense not to use curly brackets here, but I still think this question is specifically valuable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an array as an array [subscript](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html):

```
x = {'apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear'};
y = [2 4 3 1]; 
z = x(y);
```

This code assigns creates a cell array `z` that contains the elements from `x`, that are selected by the indices `y`, in the order of the indices. (that is the basics of MATLAB *subscripting*; other methods of indexing are *linear* and *logical*, see [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/) site for details).